# Unity converting int to double

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting the players current x velocity, then attempting to multiply it when the player jumps. This information comes in the form of a double, so I've (attempted) to convert it to INT form inside the "rv" variable. However, everytime that I do this, it seems to take the form of a double again.

Error message:
Assets/player.cs(137,39): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'float'

Code:

```cs
void Jump(){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (isGrounded || Time.time - lastTimeGrounded <= rememberGroundedFor || additionalJumps > 0) && sinceDash > dashTime){
            if(timesincejump>30){
                timesincejump = 0;
                int rv = Mathf.RoundToInt(rb.velocity.x);
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rv*1.12, jumpForce); 
                additionalJumps--;
            }
        }else{
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
                preJumpedTime = 0;
            }
        }
    

    }
```

Comment: From the error message, it looks like `Vector2`'s constructor expects a float (i.e. `rv * 1.12f`) but you're creating a `double` (i.e. `rv * 1.12`).

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar [it does indeed](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-ctor.html), basically everything in Unity uses `float` instead of `double`. I vote to close this as typo-based as this is a broadly known fact

Answer (score 3):

Unity Vectors requires `float` values in order to be used;

You need to add the keyword "f" after every decimal number in order to be recognized as a `float` and not a `double`. C# expect a suffix to not interpret every decimal number as a double.

```
var x = 1.2;  // This is a double!
var y = 1.2f; // This is float!
```

So `rb.velocity.x` comes from `rb.velocity` wich is a `Vector2`, and it's values are `float`s.

---

Besides that also instead of converting to `int` and then multiplying with a decimal again, it would be better if you stick to `float` right away.

There's no need for this

```
int rv = Mathf.RoundToInt(rb.velocity.x);
```

Rather store `rb.velocity.x` only if you will need further, you can directly use this value, like:

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x * 1.12f, jumpForce);
```

Comment: Usually I'd say don't answer typo based questions, but your point about the `int` is actually a very good one as well!

Comment: Yeah I'm new but I've read about "helping rules". I want to thank you for formatting and making my english more understandable. I did answer because these kind of unnecessary convertions and trying to use double as float were a lot common when I was learning the basics. I also didn't know if I should've pointed that or rather go for the solution, but since you're older here, I guess it's fine.